# Comment form/submission trouble?

Tags: php, html, css, forms, comments

***Please note: the site I'm working with doesn't allow the use of Javascript. It's a huge pain, but I can't do anything about it. I'm looking for (hopefully) a work around for my problem.***

This is a bit of a weird situation, so I'm going to try and explain my problem as best as possible without getting too complicated.

I write style sheets and stuff for this site I go on called AniRoleplay, which is basically an cheap knock-off version of the old Myspace. I was making a custom bulletin, trying to move the comment section to another location on the page. To do that, I copy/pasted the form that the site uses by default to post comments.

That code is as follows:

```
<table align='center' class='txt_label'>
<tr>
    <td width='100%'><p align='left'> <font face='Verdana' color='#000000' size='2'> <b>Add a Comment :</b> </font> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width='100%'><p align='left'>
            <textarea id='textarea1' name='comment_text' rows='5' cols='30' style='width:700; height:75'></textarea>
            <br>
            <br>
            <b><font color='black'>Your image will display properly if this URL ends in .GIF, .PNG or .JPG. Anything else will not work.</font></b><br>
            <input name='image' type='text' size='95' style='width:700px' placeholder='Image URL --- EXAMPLE: http://i.imgur.com/s7BBFmm.JPG'/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr> </tr>
<tr>
    <td width='100%'><p align='left'>
            <INPUT class=flat id=Submit onclick=document.theForm.details.value=idContent.document.body.innerHTML; type=submit value='Add Comment' name=Submit>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

However, when I added it and tested it.. I got this error from the site:

***"You did not enter any text for your comment."***

The result I'm looking for is something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XaOg.jpg

I got that result by accident, but had no idea how I had gotten it. I ended up going back to an older version of the layout though because the submit button wasn't responding, but even when I did get it to respond, I kept constantly running into the "no text" error.

Last but not least, here's the link to the CodePen I have been working on for this layout: http://codepen.io/Peechiee/pen/qOBQZe?editors=110

I have seriously run out of ideas here. D: I don't know anything about PHP (I'm self taught and am pretty much only familiar with CSS and HTML) so I don't know if that is relevant to the situation but I'd really really appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The attributes don't have quotes? This `onclick=document.theForm.details.value=idContent.document.body.innerHTML;`  is JS. What does the PHP look like? You've already searched the code base for `You did not enter any text for your comment`? If the form is submitting to PHP, which given your note about no js it sounds like it is, then it is relevant.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where to find the PHP files, all I know is that it leads to a document called "comment_bulletin.php" I think? But I don't know where that is.. I'll give you the source code pages for both the bulletin page and the error page though.

Bulletin page: view-source:www.aniroleplay.com/view_journal.php?journal_id=98451

Error page: view-source:www.aniroleplay.com/comment_bulletin.php?journal_id=98446

Comment: What is the form's `action`?

Comment: The forms action is: "comment_bulletin.php?journal_id=98451"

Comment: Okay then yes we need `comment_bulletin.php`. Should be in the same directory as the script calling it or rewritten via `.htaccess`.

Comment: That's where I run into trouble. I tried searching for the link on the page using CTRL+F but there's no link to it. I don't know how to get to it. I have never heard of .htaccess ... What is that?

Comment: You said you copied and pasted from a different file, is that other file in the same directory as the one you are working on?

Comment: You need server access. `.htaccess`, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess, is an apache file that handles a number of things. You will also need server access to access `.php` files. Server side scripts are only available on the server.

Comment: This sounds like it is going to be a long path, I'm bowing out. @WhiteRabbit use the `@` to tag future commentors.

Comment: I took what I could find from view source, since I don't know where to find the original documents, as I am not an admin for the site or anything like that.

Comment: @WhiteRabbit you can this message search in file content. in whole root folder and subfolders